# How can I break the function to-do list into separate parts

Tags: javascript, dom

I made a to-do list, when adding an item, it can be edited and deleted. How can rewrite the function createEditAndDeleteElement so that it is less cumbersome or how to break it up into several parts. When I tried to break it, it displayed an error with li. Please, help

```
const input = document.getElementById('list');
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
const toDoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(input.value === '') {
        return
    }
    createEditAndDeleteElement(input.value) 
    input.value ='';
});

function createEditAndDeleteElement(value) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const btnDelete = document.createElement('button');
    const btnEdit = document.createElement('button');
    li.className = 'todo-list-item';
    li.textContent = value;
    btnDelete.className = 'btn-delete';
    btnDelete.textContent = 'delete';
    btnEdit.className = 'btn-edit';
    btnEdit.textContent = 'edit';
    li.appendChild(btnDelete);
    li.appendChild(btnEdit);

    btnDelete.addEventListener('click', () => {
        toDoList.removeChild(li);
    });

    btnEdit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const editInput = document.createElement('input');
    const saveEdit= document.createElement('button');
    saveEdit.className = 'btn-save';
    saveEdit.textContent = 'Save';
    toDoList.removeChild(li);  
    toDoList.appendChild(editInput);
    toDoList.appendChild(saveEdit);
    editInput.value = li.textContent;
    saveEdit.addEventListener('click', () => {
        toDoList.removeChild(editInput);
        toDoList.removeChild(saveEdit);
        createEditAndDeleteElement(editInput.value)
    })
    });
    
    toDoList.appendChild(li);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a templates: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

```js
let template = document.getElementById('newElement');
let templateContent = template.content;
document.getElementById('addNew').onclick = createElement

function createElement() {
  document.body.appendChild(templateContent);
}

function handleActions(action){
  console.log(action) 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="addNew">Test</button>
  <template id="newElement">
    <button onclick="handleActions('Action 1')">Action1</button>
    <button onclick="handleActions('Action 2')">Action2</button>
  </template>
</body>
```